# Travelling around a graph and making predictions along the way

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, bayesian

I'm a student doing research and am having trouble proceeding because I don't have much experience in this field, so even if you can't answer the questions but do know important terms I should be looking for that would be a big help.

If we have an agent travelling around a graph, going from node to node, are there algorithms (and if so, the names of algorithms) that do the following:

1. Predict the topology of the graph using bayesian statistics, which assumes the graph is finite and what has been seen before increasingly represents what will be seen in the future.
2. Can predict labellings from previous labellings. So if we have a chain of 26 nodes, with the first node being A, the second B, so on and so, then at some point you should be able to predict that the labellings are in alphabetical order long before we reach the end.
3. Use the labellings to predict the topology of the graph; so if I have a graph where so far it is a chain and the labellings are clearly alphabetical order, then a good guess for the rest of the graph would be that it is a chain.
4. Relevant API would be fantastic

Comment: This question if interesting but quite broad. Could you provide us with a graph and a possible answer to make it understandable what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So say you start at a leaf node which is labelled as A and store. You move to the only other node it is connected to and see it is labelled as B and store that info. Then you move to the only other node it is connected to and it is labelled as C and store that info. A reasonable guess would be at the next node it will also be of degree two or degree one and it will be labelled "D". I was hoping that the graphs it would generate would preserve as much as possible the distribution and average vertex degree, and in my example could put as a likely answer that the number of nodes is 26 or less.